# New version of axis2 (OMSourcedElementImpl)

Tags: java, constructor, apache-axis, axiom

Now I have such code:

```
  public org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement getOMElement (
               final javax.xml.namespace.QName parentQName,
               final org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory factory) throws org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException{

               org.apache.axiom.om.OMDataSource dataSource =
                       new org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBDataSource(this,parentQName){

                 public void serialize(javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter) throws javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException {
                       WSExceptionType.this.serialize(parentQName,factory,xmlWriter);
                 }
               };
               return new org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl(
               parentQName,factory,dataSource);

       }
```

I need to use new version of Axis2 - 1.7.5 in my project.

The new version of library **axiom-impl-1.2.20.jar** doesn't contain constructor of **OMSourcedElementImpl** class with such parameters, but without parameters only.
How can I solve this issue to have the same functionality with new libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code was generated with an old version of Axis2. You need to regenerate it with Axis2 1.7.5.